# TFS not showing Dev branch in target locations for merging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, merge

s/w versions:
TFS2008 server, VS2010, windows xp

I have the following branch structure in TFS

- $/Root/Main Branch
- $/Root/Dev/Project1

Project1 was branched off the Main Branch, few months ago. Now I need to merge the latest code in the Main Branch to the Project1 branch. During that time, some new folders were added to the Main Branch.(Main Branch/CoreDataClasses/..). So when I try to merge this new folder into the Project1 branch using the merge wizard, I don't see the Project1 branch in the list of target branches. Why is TFS not showing me my dev branch in the target branches list?

Comment: Can you please tell me did you faced this problem after migrating from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your merge from the root (where you branched), not the individual folder(s).  Remember that merges aren't destructive until you check in, so you can choose to only check in the new folders if you want to hold off other changes.

Comment: I tried doing a merge from the root folder (/Root/Main Branch to /Root/Dev/Project1) but TFS gives the error TF30041: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Contact your TFS admin.

Comment: Now that's not a problem with merging. That indicates the application tier can't talk to the data tier. Make sure ne database is up.

Answer (score 1):

With Tfs I've had much better experience merging from **branch to the trunk** and I think this might be the case here.  Of course this might take a rethink of your strategy but it's doable.

I know this may be way offside but if you're doing cross branch merging a lot then definitely consider a distributed version control system like **mercurial**.  I've used Tfs lots and really like it but when it comes to branching and merging it is a distant second to hg merge (mercurial command)

Answer (score -4):

The folder structure between source and target have to be the at least 80% the same. If there was too many restructuring of the folder layout then I suggest you use the cmd line Merge with the force switch when doing the merge. See "[Merge Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx)".

Comment: please cite the source of your "80% the same" answer.  While deletes and renames might cause problems when merging, TFS doesn't compare trunk / branch until you initiate the merge.

Comment: @Robaticus- Thats what I meant when I said folder structure which is issues relating to delete and rename. If it is a minor differences of folder structure then TFS will be able to merge it. Most cases I had to force merge it and the downside to that is the history of that specific files might be lost. My 80% answer comes from my own experience on what I encountered. This is the problem with TFS 2008 and I am not sure if TFS2010 resolve this intelligently.